# BIOS Password on Gateway NE56R10U

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a Windows 7 64bit Gateway NE56R10U.

I forgot the BIOS Password. CMOSPWD, KillCMOS, you name it,

nothing works! How do I crack the BIOS without doing anything Dangerous like:

---

- Flashing BIOS
- Playing with Circuit Boards
- Removing things
- etc.

---

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Reset BIOS/CMOS settings? Check your motherboards manual for that. Or remove the battery from the motherboard.

Comment: new edit. looky